# Gets ENOTDIR error when yarn start for expo project

Tags: react-native, expo, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

I activated yarn by following yarn official docs (https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

I created an expo app with yarn by following react native official docs (https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

But when I run `yarn start` I get below error

```
node:internal/errors:465
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:700:9)
    at spawn (/Users/minseok/Repository/test/.yarn/cache/cross-spawn-npm-6.0.5-2deab6c280-f893bb0d96.zip/node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js:12:24)
    at run (/Users/minseok/Repository/test/.yarn/unplugged/expo-npm-46.0.10-310b54dc3f/node_modules/expo/bin/cli.js:11:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/minseok/Repository/test/.yarn/unplugged/expo-npm-46.0.10-310b54dc3f/node_modules/expo/bin/cli.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require$$0.Module._extensions..js (/Users/minseok/Repository/test/.pnp.cjs:20807:33)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.require$$0.Module._load (/Users/minseok/Repository/test/.pnp.cjs:20630:22) {
  errno: -20,
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Same problem. Did you find a solution?